Upgrade failed 22.04 to 24.04.1 - help needed - urgent
I tried to upgrade from 22.04 and 24.04.1. After a long process during which I could see a few errors (thunderbird, etc..), it finally displayed a dialogue box that said something in the lines of 'Upgrade aborted. Your system may be in an unusable state. A recovery will be attempted...' - when I click ok, it just silently exited. I'm still able to access the system and haven't rebooted yet. I'm in the GUI and can access terminal. In terminal when I check of release version it says I'm on 24.04
$ lsb_release -r
No LSB modules are available.
Release:    24.04

$ uname -a
Linux M-T470 5.15.0-128-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Sat Nov 30 22:28:23 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


But somethings don't seem to work right. For instance, gpg displays this error, when I attempt to decrypt:
gpg: AES256.CFB encrypted data
gpg: WARNING: server 'gpg-agent' is older than us (2.2.27 < 2.4.4)
gpg: Note: Outdated servers may lack important security fixes.
gpg: Note: Use the command "gpgconf --kill all" to restart them.
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase

Considering that I haven't rebooted yet, wanted to know, how should I proceed? what can I do to salvage the system. (I understand that if all fails, I'll need to do fresh install from a live usb. I've taken a backup)
But given the current state - is there anything you'd recommend to cleanup state and attempt to get back to a stable release?
This is a Lenovo Thinkpad T470. I have dualboot with windows.
(Unfortunately, I can not hold this state for long, as I need to head out on a trip and need to take this laptop. Not enough time to do a fresh install. This is just about the worst time for this to happen - I should have been more careful. Would be grateful for any quick guidance. Thanks.)
Update: I also found the following here
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo reboot

Should I try this? Do I do it before or after reboot?
UPDATE:
So I did a sudo apt --fix-broken install and it returned back fine except asking me to do a sudo apt-get autoremove. I did this and about 900 MB of space was recovered. Post this, sudo dpkg --configure -a and it too returned back with no errors. I then did an apt update, followed by upgrade. The upgrade complained of issues with xdaignose, which I removed. After this I repeated the autoremove, update, upgrade - all came back fine reporting nothing to be done. I then fired up software update, which checked for updates and said that I needed a restart to complete the updates. So I did a reboot. It went fine and I am backup in the GUI.
Now I am able to see this:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

and the gpg errors have gone too. I then removed thunderbird too.
So it all seems to be looking fine now. I seem to be on 24.04.1.
Please let me know if there are any additional steps that I can do to check that the upgrade has been completed correctly with no issues.

Is this an encrypted install? Have you tried sudo apt update and then sudo apt upgrade What brand/model system? Do you need proprietary drivers like nVidia or Wi-Fi as those do not upgrade and need reinstall. Post any errors you get. What does this show? uname -a I think we need more info on what failed to know what to repair.

it is not a encrypted install. output from gpg is just an example when I tried to decrypt a file I manually encrypted.  On what failed - I don't exactly know. I know it complained about thunderbird and about some 'system process' and xfailsafe or something like that. Is there a log file it leaves? If so I can post that. Will update the output of 'uname -a' and system details in the post. I haven't done a sudp apt update or upgrade. Wanted to check here first. Should I reboot and try sudo apt update or upgrade?

It seems unclear, after reading multiple edits, if you still have a question or not.

"Please let me know if there are any additional steps that I can do to check that the upgrade has been completed correctly with no issues." - this is the question that remains. How can I verify the upgrade has been completed correctly?
